# How should I interpret this residuals plot

Tags: regression, residuals

Doing my thesis I came up on a problem where I can't find the answer on.
I have a dataset with only categorical predictors with sometimes many levels and a numeric outcome variable bounded between zero and 1. The outcome variable is a given discount percent variable.  It is not normally distributed with more then two modes:

[image]

In this case I used 5 predictor variables and Nrows around 850.000
I tried several different algorithms ( betareg, lm, anova, random forest, svr ) But every time this residuals vs fitted plot comes up:

[image]

Also when I use a smaller training you will see this downwards trend.

My question is how to interpet this plot and is there a way to deal with this since all my predictor variables are categoric?

I try to find out witch variables of a 200 variables wide dataset have a impact on the given discounts.

Thanks,

Comment: You have non-constant variance in residuals, model behaves more badly where your model predicts bigger discount.

Comment: If you use beta regression, then don't worry about residuals being non-normally distributed. That's an assumption of standard linear regression with a Gaussian (identity) link function.

Answer (score 1):

If your response is bounded between 0 and 1, you don't conform to the assumptions of a linear regression, and it is thus not surprising that you don't get normal residuals.

You can model 0/1 proportional data in a number of ways. A common approach is a beta regression.